# Jquery using time out to execute code

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function below pauses revolution slider on page load and resumes play when the user clicks on the #close_cross button. How do I add a time out of 10 seconds so when the user fails to click the #close_cross close button, the slider resumes play anyway?

```
<script>
    // pause slider
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".rev_slider_wrapper").each(function(){
$this = jQuery(this);
id_array = $this.attr("id").split("_");
id = id_array[2];
jQuery.globalEval( 'revapi'+id+'.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e)          {revapi'+id+'.revpause();});' );
});
}); 

// play slider on pop up close

    jQuery("#close_cross").on('click', function() {     jQuery(".rev_slider_wrapper").each(function(){
$this = jQuery(this);
id_array = $this.attr("id").split("_");
id = id_array[2];
jQuery.globalEval( 'revapi'+id+'.revresume();' );
}); });

</script>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use globalEval()

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the resume code into a separate function.

This is untested, but it should give you the idea:

```
// pause slider
jQuery(".rev_slider_wrapper").each(function(){
  $this = jQuery(this);
  id_array = $this.attr("id").split("_");
  id = id_array[2];
  jQuery.globalEval( 'revapi'+id+'.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e){revapi'+id+'.revpause();});' );
});

function resumeSlider(){
  jQuery(".rev_slider_wrapper").each(function(){
    $this = jQuery(this);
    id_array = $this.attr("id").split("_");
    id = id_array[2];
    jQuery.globalEval( 'revapi'+id+'.revresume();' );
  });
}

// play slider on pop up close
jQuery("#close_cross").on('click', resumeSlider); 

setTimeout(function(){
  resumeSlider();
  jQuery("#close_cross").off('click');
}, 10000);
```

Also, as epascarello says, I'm sure that it is not necessary to use `globalEval()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the basic [setTimeout (@ MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) function for that.

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("put the play code here")}, 10000);
```